# Finding the sample variance from a single factor study

Tags: statistics, variance

I have a dataset that contains two features: type of treatment and rate. Some example data would be the following:

```
   trt rate
1    1    100.25
2    1     97.33
3    1    102.46
...
```

This is a single-factor study. I was asked to get the value for the sample variance $ s^2 $. Usually, I use the following formula to find sample variance: $ \frac{\sum{x - \bar{x}}}{n - 1} $. However, the notes I was given also give me the following formula:

$$ s^2 = \sqrt{MSE} $$

After calculating the variance both ways, I got following:

using $ \frac{\sum{x - \bar{x}}}{n - 1} $
$$ s^2 = 71.323 $$

using $ s^2 = \sqrt{MSE} $
$$ s^2 = 53.0 $$

So I am wondering why there is a difference between the two values? and which one is really $s^2$ of this dataset?

Comment: how many treatments do you have and of what would you like to compute the sample variance? the variable rate?

Comment: I have four treatments, and I am just asked for s^2 (there is no specification for a specific treatment variance)

Comment: it is difficult to answer then because there are multiple sample variances, e.g. the variance between treatments, the group variance, the overall variance. in general, $MSE = VAR + BIAS^2$ so if an estimate is unbiased, $MSE = VAR$. Thus, $\sqrt{MSE}$ can be used to estimate the standard deviation of unbiased estimators (not the variance)

Comment: so for the overall variance, would it be better to use MSE or would the first formula be a better representation of the overall variance

Comment: it really depends on what you want to do. the variance is the more common quantity to be reported because it can be interpreted as a measure of how the data spreads. the mse on the other hand is a quantity which is typically of interest if you are concerned with particular estimates